# update one table based on values of another table using case when then

Tags: mysql, sql

Getting MY SQL syntax error also not sure if my approach is correct.
matchScore in one table should be updated to another table based on the below condition:

1. 100 -> 0
2. 97-99 -> .1
3. 95-96 -> .2

```
    create table A(id int, matchScore int, PRIMARY KEY(id))
    create table b(id, int, matchScore double, PRIMARY KEY(id))
    UPDATE
      b
    SET
      [b.matchScore] = (CASE WHEN A.matchScore = 100 THEN 0 END)
    FROM
      b,
      A
    where
      A.id = b.id
```

100 in A should be 0 in b
97-99 if value is 97, 98,99 in A then in b it should be .1
95-96 if value is 95, 96 in A then in b it should be    .2

Comment: sql its shown as tag

Comment: what is the problem with the question that it is down voted?

Comment: SQL is a language defined by ANSI/ISO. That UPDATE FROM is not included in the SQL standard.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you should show us sample table data for all tables involved. You should also specify the expected result. Take a look at [mcve] too.

Comment: [Why should I tag my RDBMS?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms/)

Comment: Among other things, you have commas after your `id` column names in the `CREATE TABLE` statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can  try below update query -

```
UPDATE b
INNER JOIN a ON b.id = a.id
SET b.matchScore = CASE WHEN a.matchScore = 100 THEN 0
                        WHEN a.matchScore between 97 and 99 then .1
                        WHEN a.matchScore between 95 and 96 then .2 END;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=eaa0e9976171ed2ed8493f42db9a059e) is the fiddle.